# visual studio code - python - tkinter

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, canvas

```
import tkinter 
canvas = tkinter.Canvas()

canvas.pack()
tkinter.mainloop()
canvas.create_text(150, 100, text = "HELLO")
```

## Hello.

Sorry for my English. Start in Python.
Canvas is on screen, but NO text
What is wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your code isn't executed. You call tkinter.mainloop(), which basically stops execution of all code after it. Here, replace it with this instead:

```
import tkinter 
canvas = tkinter.Canvas()

canvas.pack()
canvas.create_text(150, 100, text = "HELLO")
tkinter.mainloop()
```

Make sure "tkinter.mainloop()" comes after the code, so it executes.

I hope this helps. Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

Simply because you use `.mainloop()` before creating your text. Put your `create_text` line just under the one where you create the canvas and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what You were looking for:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas


root = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()

canvas.create_text(150, 100, text='Hello')

root.mainloop()
```

Tho looking at Your code I would say You have to take a look at some basic python tutorials as well as some tkinter tutorials. You really need them! For example this [about tkinter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YXPyB4XeYLA)

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs because you are using `root.mainloop` this means that everything before it runs but everything after the `root.mainloop` runs when you close the program.

So if you want to see the text on the canvas do this:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_text(150, 100, text = "HELLO")

root.mainloop()
```